# Firebase Authentication Page Continual Refresh Upon Reroute

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a Firebase web app and when the user logins, they're redirected to another page, but once they're rerouted to a new page the page is on a continual loop of refreshing. I've searched all over but can't seem to find an answer.

**Here's my snippet for rerouting:**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    window.location = 'userDashboard.html'; //After successful login, user will be redirected to home.html
  } else {
    break;
  }
});
```

**My question:**

Any idea why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work without page refresh. What I did was change out `onAuthStateChanged` to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

**Updated Snippet:**

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(user => {
    // Sign in success
    window.location = 'dashboard.html';
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you are reloading the webpage and executing your rerouting code again. Make sure you only have that code on the login page.